# Google-Maps-for-Rails center map via ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I'm setting a new marker via ajax and I was wondering how to center the map on the new point with a custom zoom level, I made in this way:

```
  def geocode
pos = Gmaps4rails.geocode(params[:address])
render :update do |page|
    unless pos.blank?
        page << "$('#poi_latitude').val(#{pos.first[:lat]});"
        page << "$('#poi_longitude').val(#{pos.first[:lng]});"
        page << "if (marker != null) { marker.setMap(null); }"
        page << "var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(#{pos.first[:lat]},#{pos.first[:lng]});"
        page << "marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: myLatlng, map: Gmaps4Rails.map});"
                    page << "Gmaps4Rails.map.centerAndZoom(myLatlng, 0);"

    end
end
```

end

but I get an error because the method centerAndZoom is not defined into gmaps4rails.js, should i define it into the js or there is another way?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Gmaps4rails` is a wrapper, so google objects keep all their properties.

Your line `Gmaps4Rails.map.centerAndZoom(myLatlng, 0);` doesn't work since `centerAndZoom` isn't a valid method (where did you find it? the reference is here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html )

Otherwise, your question is already answered here: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Dynamic-%28or-Ajax%29-map-refresh

You can use either `replace_markers` or `add_markers`.

And you can adapt the settings of your map to center it the way you want: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Map

See `auto_adjust` in particular.

Comment: The links in this answer no longer contain the solution.